# 60 Hz buzz on output of DC power supply

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, audio, noise

I have a 120 V AC to 5 V DC power supply for an audio board. I’m getting the 60 Hz buzz on the output and getting about 44 V AC on the DC output as well. I already replaced two capacitors that were visibly bad, but hum is still there. I’m thinking I have another bad capacitor or resistor somewhere but not sure where or how to look for it. I have a multimeter and capacitor tester and clearly I have missed something. Any info on how to figure out what the problem is would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which capacitors you replaced? Also, did you by any chance not mount it on earthed metal chassis, or left the metal chassis ungrounded, or simply plugged this with ungrounded plug or to an ungrounded socket?

Comment: I replaced the two capacitors directly to the right of the transistor near the DC output. They were the 1000uf 10v caps. I had the board installed so it was grounded while testing

Comment: *Visibly bad capacitors*? PCB date (2013) suggests fairly new, past the electrolytic plague ending about 2007. So check for bad diodes that might have caused their failure. Also ensure that DC output pins are very high resistance to earth and to line and to neutral.

Comment: The two caps I replaced were visibly bad, bulging tops. I will check the other things you mentioned

Comment: Sounds like Y-capacitor leakage to me. Ground the minus output and measure if it goes away.

Comment: Ground the minus output of the capacitor? Or ground the minus output of the DC output ?